# IntelliJ (MAC) Could not determine java version from '9.0.1' - Trying to make an Android App

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

Is there anyone here familiar with `IntelliJ` that could tell me what I might be doing wrong?

I'm trying to work with IntelliJ to make a brand new Android project and when I create a new android project and try to build it I get an error saying

> "Could not determine java version from '9.0.1'."

I've downloaded `Android Studio` and didn't have the same problem but I am required to use `IntelliJ` to complete this project.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, the exact error is "Could not determine java version from '9.0.1'."

Comment: change the gradle version ,it seems to solve the above issue

Comment: @GOKUL, I tried changing it and that didn't seem to help.  I have the SDK manager installed so I can basically install any version should I switch the default around to a couple of different versions.

Answer (score 0):

That seems like [this bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-181427). Try [2017.3.1](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download) version which contains the fix.

Note that it is still recommended to run IDE under 1.8 JDK, see [Selecting the JDK version the IDE will run under](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879) document about how to set runtime JRE for IDE.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work, I tried installing the 2017.3.1 version but ended up having to move to Android studio for Android development.